# How to process two separated inner joins?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

im doing a query and im having a bit of a trouble. This is my query:

```
SELECT u. file_id, u.row_id, u.col005,
       cl.client_id, cl.name
FROM uimp_buf_in u 
INNER JOIN(
SELECT c.client_id, c.name FROM clients c
)cl ON convert(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(cl.name), ' '), '-'),extract_title(cl.name)),'us7ascii')=
       convert(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(u.col005), ' '), '-'),extract_title(u.col005)),'us7ascii') 
INNER JOIN(
SELECT us.idusr, us.full_name FROM USERS us
)us ON convert(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(us.full_name), ' '), '-'),extract_title(us.full_name)),'us7ascii')=
       convert(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(u.col005), ' '), '-'),extract_title(u.col005)),'us7ascii') 
WHERE u.file_id = 850
```

Is there a way i can show results from first inner join, and under it results from second? Like two sepparated comparisons but in one query? In other words i need to get results for first join and then from second but without first join affecting second in any way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the results of 2 queries to appear in a single output then you are probably looking to use UNION or UNION ALL

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm

I have had a go at separating out your code and unioning them together, but I haven't tested it.

```
SELECT
    c.client_id,
    c.name
FROM
    clients c
INNER JOIN
    uimp_buf_in u 
ON  convert(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(cl.name), ' '), '-'),extract_title(cl.name)),'us7ascii')
  = convert(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(u.col005), ' '), '-'),extract_title(u.col005)),'us7ascii')
WHERE
    u.file_id = 850

UNION ALL

SELECT
    us.idusr,
    us.full_name
FROM
    USERS us
INNER JOIN
    uimp_buf_in u
ON  convert(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(us.full_name), ' '), '-'),extract_title(us.full_name)),'us7ascii')
  = convert(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(u.col005), ' '), '-'),extract_title(u.col005)),'us7ascii')
WHERE
    u.file_id = 850
```